# What is an efficient workflow with C? - Makefile + bash script

Tags: c, bash, makefile, compilation

I'm working on one of my first projects that will span more than one C file. For my first couple practice programs, I just wrote my code in `main.c` and compiled using `gcc main.c -o main`. This worked for me as I was learning.

Now, I'm working on a much bigger project on my own. I want to continue doing compilation on my own (or at least setting it up manually) so I can understand the process. After reading a bit, I decided to make a Makefile.

Note: I'm also using GTK+, so I had to look up how to add that into the compile command.

This is what it looks like after a bit of research:

```
main:
    gcc -Wall -g main.c -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

At first, I was just running "make". Then I was having some problems getting the error "main is up to date" even though I had changed the file.

So I wrote a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm main
make
./main
```

So I make changes, and then  I run this script.

Is this a good/normal system? I want to have scalable system, since my project will grow. I assume I can keep that script and just add dependencies to the makefile and change the main compile command in the makefile. Am I correct?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the feedback about how to fix my Makefile.

So is the typical compilation process 1) type `make` then 2) `./main` regardless of how the project is setup or its size (assuming you've written a proper makefile)?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You first do a `make` and then do a `./main`

Comment: Great, thanks! Seems rather easy to learn so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell make that `main` depends on `main.c`. That way every time you make changes to `main.c` and then run `make`, `main` is regenerated. To delete `main` you can have a phony target called `clean` as:

```
main:main.c
    gcc -Wall -g main.c -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f main
```

Now to delete `main` you can do : `make clean`

If you get `make: main is up to date.` It means you've not modified `main.c` and hence there is not need for regenerating `main`. But if you have to force regenerating `main` even when the dependencies have not been updated you can also use the `-B` option of `make` as suggested by [Sjoerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624200/what-is-an-efficient-workflow-with-c-makefile-bash-script/3624235#3624235) in other answer.

Comment: It's useful to add a line `.PHONY: clean` above the the `clean` target just in case a file named 'clean' (A shell script for instance) ends up in the directory. If that happens, make will see the file and not run the clean target. `PHONY` tells it to not even look.

Answer (score 3):

- Use `make -B` or `make --always-make` to compile even though the target is up to date
- Append filenames after the colon to check whether these are updated.

Example:

```
a: a.c
        gcc -o a a.c
```

`a` would only be built if `a.c` is newer than `a`.

Comment: For a larger project, `make -B` is probably not what people want to use.

Comment: Right. -B would be useful if the modified time of some files are incorrect. This happens for example when you copy something over your output file.

Answer (score 3):

I find command-line `make` to be quite sufficient for my needs, but writing `Makefiles` by hand becomes quite a chore. As your project grows in complexity, you'll find managing the dependencies by hand to become more and more annoying. What I suggest you do is learn how to do at least one of the following:

- Write a dependency-tracking `Makefile` by calling e.g., `gcc -M`.
- Learn to use a `Makefile` generator such as `automake` or `CMake`. I personally prefer `automake` because it is more mature (and doesn't do stupid things like try to put semicolon-separated lists on a command line).

Comment: +1 for mentioning available Makefile generators. I'll check them out.