# Problem with makefile

Tags: c, makefile

hiii , i just started studying makefiles and wrote the following one for a simple hello.c file. it shows some error saying :

> makefile1:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.

What is the wrong here ... ?

```
 CC=gcc
    CFLAGS=-c -Wall

    hello: hello.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) hello.c -o hello

    clean:
     rm -rf *.o
```

And , Is it always a better option to use a makefile or there are any specific cases to not use them ...?

Please correct me if i am wrong anywhere ...

Comment: BTW `make` has implicit rules for many file types, so you can just write `hello: hello.c` without writing next line with command. `CC` and `CFLAGS` will be used by implicit rule.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not missing any tabs before you write the rule to generate a target:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

hello: hello.c
<TAB>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) hello.c -o hello

.PHONY: clean
clean:
<TAB>rm -rf *.o
```

Its good to write the `.PHONY`. You can find the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624200/what-is-an-efficient-workflow-with-c-makefile-bash-script/3624228#3624228).

Comment: Now it says ... 
 " NO rule to make target hello.c , needed by hello ".... what does that mean ?

Comment: Looks like there is no file named `hello.c` in the directory.

Comment: It compiled.. It showed me "$(CC) $(CFLAGS) hello.c -o hello" ...
but when i try to compile suing ./hello it doesnt....Any idea why the prblem is ...?

Comment: `./hello` does not compile..its runs. What do you get when you do `./hello`?

Comment: I get bash: /hello:permission denied... I meant to say "run" sry for the worng term.. This occurs even when i am the super user...

Answer (score 1):

First, your targets should not be indented. Second, make sure you're using tab characters not spaces to indent.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
.PHONY: clean # There's no clean file.
hello: hello.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) hello.c -o hello
clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

As to your other question, makefiles are used everywhere. Whether you like them or not, learning how to maintain them is a good idea. Personally, I like how magic they are. They can be great time savers. They can also be horrendous time sinks if you find yourself having to debug complex ones.

Answer (score 0):

"Missing separator" means you probably didn't use a tab character in your CC or rm lines.  Try reformatting the file as follows

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

hello: hello.c
<TAB>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) hello.c -o hello

clean:
<TAB>rm -rf *.o
```

Make is picky in that all command lines must lead with a tab character.  Not 4 spaces, not 8 spaces, but an actual tab (ASCII 0x09).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to indentation problems, you should drop `-c` from CFLAGS, else the produced hello will not be an executable but a .o file without the correct name.